# Dividing image into patches and getting patch index of one pixel

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a matrix of size 1080 x 667 (e.g. representing an image). Now I would like to divide this matrix into quadratic non-overlaping patches row-wise and when a (x,y) coordinate is provided (i.e. one pixel in the image), I need the patch number. I thought about a method with the declaration:

```
def get_patch_index(image_dim, patch_dim, x, y)
```

`image_dim` is the dimension of the matrix (1080, 667). patch_dim is the patch size (e.g. 3,3) and `x` and `y` is the pixel to evaluate.

For example, a call `get_patch_index((1080,667), (3,3), 0, 0)` should return an index 0 (the first patch) and a call `get_patch_index((1080,667), (3,3), 1080, 667)` should return an index 39 (the last patch).

How is it possible to efficiently implement this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more how these indexes are calculated?

Comment: how do you count patches? row or column wise? your image is not multiple of patch size in example. Is it guaranteed your image is multiple of patches? if not how do you want to handle edges?

Comment: @mathfux The indexes should just be an enumeration of the patches. The first patch has index 0, the second patch index 1 etc.

Comment: @Ehsan I count patches row wise. No the image does not need to be multiple of patches. Edges can for example be handled by just cutting patch at border of the image.

Comment: @machinery so you want uneven size patches for edges?

Comment: Why not direct division by patch size and using # of columns?

Comment: @Ehsan Yes, uneven size patches for edges. I would like to get the patch number and not the column number, i.e. the patches should be enumerated row wise.

Answer (score -2):

You can use pil library of python.
Then follow steps

1. Create matrices of patch dimension and loop through pixel
2. Put the result in order in some list or map
3. write method that has input of dimensions and searches through the map to return patch number